# Find area between the curve y = 1/(1+x^2) and the x-axis

Tags: area, between, calculus

Find area between the curve y = 1/(1+x^2) and the x-axis. This is Calculus 2. I think I have a and b correct, but not sure of c. Any help would be very much appreciated! :)

(a) from -10 to 10
Answer that I got: arctan(10)-arctan(-10) = 2.942
(b) from -A to A
Answer that I got: arctan(A)-arctan(-A)
(c) Find the area under the whole curve. (Calculate the limit of your answer in part (b) as A → ∞)
Have no idea, I think as A → ∞ then arctan(A) = pi/2, but do we also do it for -A? So would the answer be arctan(pi/2)-arctan(-pi/2)= 2?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Good job.

(a) is correct.

(b) is correct and can also be written 2*arctan(A),
because arctan(-A) = -arctan(A).

(c) careful here: arctan(A)→pi/2 as A → ∞, and arctan(-A) → -pi/2 as A → ∞,
so arctan(A) - arctan(-A) → pi.